# How to publish a constant string in the Rust FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I want to have a Rust library expose a `const char *` static string to C, to be compatible with an existing interface (specifically [librsync](http://librsync.sourcefrog.net)).  That is, the C header file has

```
extern char const *my_string;
```

In C, the library would simply have

```
char const *my_string = "hi";
```

In Rust I've tried something like

```
pub static my_string: *const libc::c_char = unsafe { "hi\0" as *const libc::c_char };
```

but this complains

```
error: casting `&'static str` as `*const i8` is invalid
```

It seems like I can't use `CString` etc because they won't be a compile-time constant expression.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need a public, static, unmangled pointer to some zero-terminated bytes:

```rust
#[export_name = "CONST_C_STR"] // or #[no_mangle]
pub static CONST_C_STR: &[u8; 20] = b"a constant c string\0";
```

This worked with a simple C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char * CONST_C_STR;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%s\n", CONST_C_STR);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for and it is certainly weird. I opened http://stackoverflow.com/q/33884184/243712 for the question of why the global isn't `Sync`.

Answer (score 2):

The crate [c_str_macro](https://crates.io/crates/c_str_macro) provides a convenience macro `c_str!`, which appends a 0 byte to a Rust string literal and presents it as a `CStr` reference.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the crate.

Comment: Curiously, [cstr!](https://crates.io/crates/cstr) crate was initially released about at the same time 3 years ago. Nowadays seems like a more popular choice. I wonder, is it all about just one underscore of difference? :)