# Why is a immutable pointer to a static immutable variable not Sync?

Tags: multithreading, rust

A static global C string (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33883281/243712)) doesn't have the [`Sync` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html).

```
pub static MY_STRING: &'static *const u8
  = "hello" as const *u8;

// TODO: Simple assertion showing it's not Sync ;)
```

`Sync` is described as

> The precise definition is: a type `T` is `Sync` if `&T` is thread-safe. In other words, there is no possibility of data races when passing `&T` references between threads.

It seems like this is entirely readonly and has static lifetime, so why isn't it safe to pass a reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chapter [*Send and Sync*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/send-and-sync.html) in [*The Rustonomicon*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/) describes what it means for a type to be `Send` or `Sync`. It mentions that:

> - raw pointers are neither Send nor Sync (because they have no safety guards).

But that just begs the question; why doesn't `*const T` implement `Sync`? Why do the safety guards matter?

Just before that, it says:

> Send and Sync are also automatically derived traits. This means that, unlike every other trait, if a type is composed entirely of Send or Sync types, then it is Send or Sync. Almost all primitives are Send and Sync, and as a consequence pretty much all types you'll ever interact with are Send and Sync.

This is the key reason why raw pointers are neither `Send` nor `Sync`. If you defined a struct that encapsulates a raw pointer, but only expose it as a `&T` or `&mut T` in the struct's API, did you really make sure that your struct respects the contracts of `Send` and `Sync`? If raw pointers were `Send`, then `Rc<T>` would also be `Send` by default, so it would have to explicitly opt-out. (In the source, there is in fact an explicit opt-out for `Rc<T>`, but it's only for documentation purposes, because it's actually redundant.)

> [...] they're [unsafe traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/safe-unsafe-meaning.html). This means that they are unsafe to implement, and other unsafe code can assume that they are correctly implemented.

OK, let's recap: they're unsafe to implement, but they're automatically derived. Isn't that a weird combination? Actually, it's not as bad as it sounds. Most primitive types, like `u32`, are `Send` and `Sync`. Simply compounding primitive values into a struct or enum is not enough to disqualify the type for `Send` or `Sync`. Therefore, you need a struct or enum with non-`Send` or non-`Sync` before you need to write an `unsafe impl`.

`Send` and `Sync` are marker traits, which means they have no methods. Therefore, when a function or type puts a `Send` or `Sync` bound on a type parameter, it's relying on the type to respect a particular contract *across all of its API*. Because of this:

> Incorrectly implementing Send or Sync can cause Undefined Behavior.